# Python code works only while debugging and not while running

Tags: python, opencv, debugging, tkinter

I'm currently grappling with a perplexing issue and would deeply appreciate any assistance. My project involves playing a video using OpenCV, advancing through it frame by frame, and simultaneously representing the current frame on a matplotlib plot with a grey line, all within a Tkinter-based GUI.

The crux of the problem is this: when I run my program normally, the grey line intended to indicate the current frame doesn't appear on the matplotlib plot. However, when I step through the code using a debugger, everything works perfectly, with the line appearing as expected.

It's also worth noting that, although I'm using Tkinter for the primary GUI, both matplotlib and OpenCV insist on opening their separate windows for display, which isn't ideal.

Here's a snippet of my code for context:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
offset = 0
cap = 0
frame_factor = 0
fps = 0
line_references = {}
last_frame = 0
def initialize_lines():
    global line_references
    all_plots = [plt.figure(fig_id).gca() for fig_id in plt.get_fignums()]

    for i, ax in enumerate(all_plots):
        line = ax.axvline(x=0, color='gray')  # Startposition der Linie
        line_references[i] = line  # Speichern der Referenz mit einem eindeutigen Schlüssel (hier Index des Plots)

def update_plots(current_frame):
    global line_references,frame_factor,offset
    current_position = (frame_factor * current_frame) / 1000 - offset


    for i, line in line_references.items():
        line.set_xdata([current_position])  # Setzt die neue Position der Linie
        line.figure.canvas.draw_idle()  # Fordert eine Neuberechnung des Plots andef update_plots(current_frame):

def play_video(file_path):
    global is_playing, cap, fps,quit_video,is_programmatic_change_trackbar,offset,frame_factor,last_frame
    duration_in_ms = int(video_duration_text_field.get())
    offset_string = video_offset_text_field.get().replace(',', '.')
    offset = float(offset_string)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)  # get fps
    total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))  # get total frames
    duration = total_frames / fps  # video duration
    cv2.namedWindow('Crash Video', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)  
   
    def trackbar_callback(pos):

        if not is_programmatic_change_trackbar:

            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos)

    cv2.createTrackbar('Frame', 'Crash Video', 0, total_frames - 1, trackbar_callback)

    frame_factor = duration_in_ms / total_frames
    is_playing = True # Video spielt ab später button hinzufügen
    initialize_lines()

    while is_playing:

        ret, frame = cap.read() 

      
        current_frame = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
        current_time = current_frame / fps 
        is_programmatic_change_trackbar = True
        cv2.setTrackbarPos('Frame', 'Crash Video', current_frame)

        is_programmatic_change_trackbar = False

        update_plots(current_frame)  # Aktualisieren der Plots

        cv2.imshow('Crash Video', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(int((1 / fps) * 1000)) 

        """if key == ord('q'):
            break
        if key == ord('s'):
            cv2.waitKey(-1)"""  # wait until any key is pressed"""

    is_playing = False
    plot_queue.put("quit")

    delete_lines()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def add_video():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a video file",
                                           filetypes=[("Video files", "*.mp4;*.avi;*.mkv"), ("All files", "*.*")])
    if file_path:
        play_video(file_path)
```

Comment: Don't know if it's the cause but generally it's bad practice to use more than 1 GUI framework in a single project. They can sometimes interfere with each other in unexpected ways. Also please provide a [mre] that we can copy+paste+run.

Comment: Matplotlib has it's own [collection of widgets](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) for integration into tkinter. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Yes you are wright i should do a minimal code everyone can run. But one problem is that  the video is perfectly fluent if i comment the update plots method. It only lags with the update plots.